# Joining same table twice in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which counts the number of orders in our SOP application were transferred directly by our customers and groups the data by week number.

```
Select To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW') As "Week No",
  Count(AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR) As "Total Orders"
From AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join ORDER_TOTALS On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
Where AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH In ('EDI', 'MODEM') And AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT =
  '<|Current year|>'
Group By To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW')
Order By "Week No"
```

Result:

```
Week No Total Orders
01  253
02  303
03  318
04  280
05  256
06  308
07  295
08  301
09  333
10  268
```

But what I want is to see an additional column that counts all other orders, but when I've altered the query it ends with 0 results and no error message, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Select To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW') As "Week No",
  Count(AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR) As EDI,
  Count(b.AUF_NR) As "Other"
From AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join ORDER_TOTALS On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
  Inner Join AUF_KOPF b On b.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
Where AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH In ('EDI', 'MODEM') And AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT =
  '<|Current year|>' And b.KOPF_SACH Not In ('EDI', 'MODEM') And
  b.ERFASS_DAT = '<|Current year|>'
Group By To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW')
Order By "Week No"
```

Result:

```
Week No EDI Other
```

Can someone point out what is wrong? All I have done is joined the table again, and reversed the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. BTW, you can probably use `case` expressions to do conditional counting, and skip the second join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone point out what is wrong?

```
FROM   AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
       Inner Join ORDER_TOTALS
       On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
       Inner Join AUF_KOPF b
       On b.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
Where  AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH In ('EDI', 'MODEM')
And    b.KOPF_SACH Not In ('EDI', 'MODEM')
```

Without any data it is difficult to be sure but my guess would be that there are no rows with the same `ORDER_NO` that have `KOPF_SACH` which are simultaneously `IN ('EDI', 'MODEM')` and `NOT IN ('EDI', 'MODEM')`. Since you are doing an `INNER JOIN` and the orders do not match both criteria simultaneously then they are excluded. You could change to using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

Or you could change from filtering in the `WHERE` clause to filtering in the `COUNT` aggregation:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW') AS "Week No",
       COUNT( CASE WHEN a.KOPF_SACH IN ('EDI', 'MODEM') THEN a.AUF_NR END )
         AS "Total Orders",
       COUNT( CASE WHEN a.KOPF_SACH NOT IN ('EDI', 'MODEM') THEN a.AUF_NR END )
         AS "Other Orders"
FROM   AUF_KOPF a
       INNER JOIN ORDER_TOTALS o
       ON ( a.AUF_NR = o.ORDER_NO )
WHERE  a.ERFASS_DAT = '<|Current year|>'
GROUP BY To_Char( a.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW' )
ORDER BY "Week No"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't needed a twice join the same tables. You may solve it with `case` or `decode`

```
Select To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW') As "Week No",
  Count(decode(AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH,'EDI', 1, 'MODEM',1)) As "Orders EDI or MODEM",
  Count(decode(AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH,'EDI', null, 'MODEM',null, 1)) As "Orders but EDI or MODEM",
  Count(AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR) As "total orders"
From AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join ORDER_TOTALS On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
Where AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT =
  '<|Current year|>'
 Group By To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW')
 Order By "Week No"
```

add one with sample data

```
with AUF_KOPF (ERFASS_DAT,KOPF_SACH, AUF_NR) as (
select sysdate, 'EDI', 1 from dual union all 
select sysdate, 'MODEM', 2 from dual union all 
select sysdate, 'EDI1', 4 from dual union all 
select sysdate, 'EDI3', 6 from dual 
)
, ORDER_TOTALS (ORDER_NO) as (
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual union all
select 1 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 4 from dual union all
select 4 from dual union all
select 6 from dual 
)
Select To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW') As "Week No",
  Count(decode(AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH,'EDI', '1', 'MODEM','1')) As "Orders EDI or MODEM",
  Count(decode(AUF_KOPF.KOPF_SACH,'EDI', null, 'MODEM',null, '1')) As "Orders but EDI or MODEM",
  Count(AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR) As "total orders"
From AUF_KOPF AUF_KOPF
  Inner Join ORDER_TOTALS On AUF_KOPF.AUF_NR = ORDER_TOTALS.ORDER_NO
Where trunc(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT,'yy') = date'2017-01-01'
 Group By To_Char(AUF_KOPF.ERFASS_DAT, 'IW')
 Order By "Week No"
```